# Python I have a column with a of number which represents a date and I cannot convert it to date format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

The format I have looks like this

> 1022021
> 7302021

these are two examples, and all the rows have the exact format where the first digit is the month, the following 2 are the day, and the last 4 are the year.

Here's what I have tried so far and the errors I got for each of them:

```
 df["Date Worked"] = pd.to_datetime( df["Date Worked"].str.slice(0,1).astype(str) + "/" + df["Date Worked"].str.slice(1,3)
                                   + '/' + df["Date Worked"].str.slice(3,7) )
```

in this case I get the following error:

> ParserError: day is out of range for month: 0/  /

```
df['Date Worked'] =pd.to_datetime( df['Date Worked'])

0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.001022021  
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.001022021  
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.001022021  
3   1970-01-01 00:00:00.001022021  
4   1970-01-01 00:00:00.001022021 


 df['Date Worked'] =pd.to_datetime( df['Date Worked'], unit = 's')



0   1970-01-12 19:53:41  
1   1970-01-12 19:53:41  
2   1970-01-12 19:53:41  
3   1970-01-12 19:53:41  
4   1970-01-12 19:53:41
```

The date value are extracted from a long string, and originally had a leading 0 but they disappeared automatically. I also tried to add a a leading zero, that didn't work, and I tried to convert it into a str and that also didn't work.

I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) to pad the dates with a leading 0 if they are less than 8 characters long. Then use `pd.to_datetime` with the [correct date format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

```
df['Date Worked'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Worked'].str.zfill(8), 
                                   format='%m%d%Y')
```

Output:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Date Worked': ['1022021', '7302021']})

   Date Worked
0      1022021
1      7302021

>>> df['Date Worked'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Worked'].str.zfill(8), 
                                       format='%m%d%Y')
>>> df

  Date Worked
0  2021-01-02
1  2021-07-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct. You should check which row has only `0` in your dataframe.